# keep header button inline with table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a little stuck on this / new with html and css.

I am trying to keep my button inline with the edge of the table.

When I resize my window, so it becomes smaller, the table stops resizing but my button keeps moving in / sticking to window edge.

How can I stop this from happening?

Below is my code snippet.

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif; /* Change your font family */
}

.header {
  height: 60px;
  /* background: #e6e6e6; */
  /* border-radius: 5px; */
  /* padding: 5px; */
}

.header .title {
  display: inline-block;

  font-size: 26px;
  margin: 14px 0px;
}

.header .addNewButton {
  float: right;
  margin: 10px 0px;

  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;

  border: 0;
  background: #009879;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
}

.content-table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 8px 0;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  min-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.content-table thead tr {
  background-color: #009879;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.content-table thead tr th:last-of-type {
  width: 20px;
}

.content-table th,
.content-table td {
  padding: 12px 15px;
}

.content-table tbody tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

.content-table tbody tr:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

.content-table tbody tr:last-of-type {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #009879;
}

.content-table tbody tr.active-row {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #009879;
}

#actions {
  /* width: 500px; */
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  /* flex-direction: row; */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
    <!-- <link href="iconfont/material-icons.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined|Material+Icons+Two+Tone|Material+Icons+Round|Material+Icons+Sharp">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <h1 class="title">Parameters</h1>
      <button type="button" class="addNewButton">
        <span>&plus; Add New</span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <table class="content-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Points</th>
          <th>Team</th>
          <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Domenic</td>
          <td>88,110</td>
          <td>dcode</td>
          <td class="material-icons">close</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="active-row">
          <td>2</td>
          <td>Sally</td>
          <td>72,400</td>
          <td>Students</td>
          <td id="actions">
            <div class="material-icons-outlined">delete</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>Nick</td>
          <td>52,300</td>
          <td>dcode</td>
          <td class="material-icons-outlined">delete</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The question is not clear, you want to keep the button out of frame just like the table?

Comment: yeah i just want the button to always be inline with the table, if it has to go out of frame or make the table stay in frame to match button

Comment: @jotehas373 Which button do you mean the "Add new " button or the "close or delete" buttons?

Comment: sorry, yeah i mean the Add New, unless you have a better way to do the delete ones also, i was still working on them

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a way for your add new button to stay fixed when you are resizing the page,hope that was what you were looking for.

first thing you should do is jumping into css and remove the float property form your ".header .addNewButton" selector.

after that you should go to ".header" selector and add display property to it and set it to flex.
finally, in your .header you should add another property named "justify-content" and set to space-around.

Comment: that almost works but it kinda centres both title and button

Comment: @jotehas373,what do you mean by centers both?you mean you don't want your title to be in same line with your button?